# Javascript and RegEx for removing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in javascript with some special characters inside.

```
var string = xxxx &dagger; yyyy &sect; zzzz
```

And I would like to remove those special characters and get only :

string = xxxx yyyy zzzz

I have tryed with this regex:

```
&#?[a-z0-9]+;
```

Like that:

```
string = string.replace(/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/g, "");
```

But the special characters are not matched with this regex.

Do you please have an idea how can I do it ?

The regex works well, see the example: http://regexr.com?31rrj

Comment: This works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/MKjb3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working fine for me.
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JwrZ6/
It's probably your syntax, strings have to be defined with " around them.

```
var string = "xxxx &dagger; yyyy &sect; zzzz";
```

NOT

```
var string = xxxx &dagger; yyyy &sect; zzzz;
```

Comment: Thanks, I sow the problem now, I converted the string in plain text and of corse, this is not working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RegExp` as follows:

```
string.replace( new RegExp( regexp_expression, 'g' ), '' );
```

Syntax for `RegExp` class is next:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern [, flags]);
```

You can read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on this class.

Comment: The regex-literal isn't his issue.

Answer (score 1):

What about using JavaScript's string.replace() method? It's probably faster, and definitely more readable than RegEx, though it might take a few lines of code.

Here's a whole writeup on replace http://www.bennadel.com/blog/142-Ask-Ben-Javascript-String-Replace-Method.htm - and Ben uses RegEx with string.replace as well. This should have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove HTML entities with a regex like so:

```javascript
function removeEntities(str) {
  return (''+str).replace(/&\w+;\s*/g, '');
}

removeEntities("xxxx &dagger; yyyy &sect; zzzz"); // => "xxxx yyyy zzzz"
```

Comment: Thanks, I sow the problem now, I converted the string in plain text and of corse, this is not working. Thanks